# Finding minimum value by group

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with objects,

```
const data = [
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":   0, "feeNumber":  4, "group": "1" },
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee": 147, "feeNumber":  6, "group": "1" },
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  20, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "1" },
  { "bankNumber": 2, "calculatedFee":  10, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "3" },
  { "bankNumber": 2, "calculatedFee": 100, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "3" },
  { "bankNumber": 3, "calculatedFee": 100, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2" },
]
```

I would like to filter this data to get the smallest value  `calculatedFee` with one `group`.

For example, `calculatedFee` = `0` is the smallest for `group` `1`, `calculatedFee` = `10` is the smallest for `group` `3`. However, what function should I create in JavaScript to get such results?

Comment: Please read [ask], as well as how to construct a [mcve]. Currently this is only a requirement, and some sample data, but without any attempt of your own, or any specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a standard 'group-by' checking on each iteration if the current `calculatedFee` is less than the previously stored value for the group or `Infinity` if the group isn't stored yet.

```js
const data = [{ bankNumber: 1, calculatedFee: 0, feeNumber: 4, group: "1", }, { bankNumber: 1, calculatedFee: 147, feeNumber: 6, group: "1", }, { bankNumber: 1, calculatedFee: 20, feeNumber: 10, group: "1", }, { bankNumber: 2, calculatedFee: 10, feeNumber: 10, group: "3", }, { bankNumber: 2, calculatedFee: 100, feeNumber: 10, group: "3", }, { bankNumber: 3, calculatedFee: 100, feeNumber: 10, group: "2", },];

const minFeesByGroup = {};

for (const datum of data) {
  if (datum.calculatedFee < (minFeesByGroup[datum.group] ?? Infinity)) {
    minFeesByGroup[datum.group] = datum.calculatedFee;
  }
}

console.log(minFeesByGroup);
```

Comment: thank you and how to add it to check if the bankNumber value is the same for a given group?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you edit your question with an example of your expected output we can offer more concrete help.